# I want to display a drop down list using antscrpt from a Folder of Text files

Tags: ant

I just have Set of text files in Windows Folder.

I want to display these filenames as drop down list for the user.

I tried with fileset and filelist but I didn't get desired output.

I HAVE USED THIS LINES OF CODE

```
<target name="all">
        <fileset id="myfileset" dir="C:\Users\MYSELF\Desktop\FOLDERNAME\test">
            <include name="*" />
        </fileset>
        <property name="files" refid="myfileset" />
        <input validargs="${files}" message="Select file Name"></input>
    </target>
```

__________-

this code generated output like this

FILE1.txt;FILE2.txt;FILE3.txt in input tag...

How can I make this output  like this

```
FILE1.txt
FILE2.txt
FILE3.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pathconvert task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) with java property `${line.separator}` to present your files one per line :

```
 <fileset id="myfileset" dir="...">
  <include name="*" />
 </fileset>

 <pathconvert property="foo" refid="myfileset" pathsep="${line.separator}"/>

  <input validargs="${foo}" message="Select file Name"></input>
```

Comment: I used pathsep="," and passed that to validargs property in input ...Then it's working fine with my requirement...Thank you